# Persist user login on my expo application with firebase v10.1.0

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I'm creating an application on react native expo, and I'm using version 10.1.0.
My problem is that when the user connects to the application and kills it, it disconnects him and he has to re-enter his login and password.
auth.onAuthChanged is placed in my authContext
for a better understanding, I'll provide you with the code for authContext.js, firebase.js and the first page displayed to the user when he starts the application to redirect him if he's logged in

first page displayed to the user to redirect him if logged:

```
const { user, loading } = useContext( AuthContext );
// if user is logged in, redirect to HomeScreen
useEffect( () => {
    Alert.alert( user?.email );
    if ( user ) {
        navigation.navigate( 'Home' );
    }
}, [ loading, user ] );
```

authContext.js :

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Alert } from "react-native";
import { auth, db } from "../config/firebase";

export const AuthContext = createContext( {
    user: null,
    setUser: () => { },
    admin: false,
} );

export const AuthProvider = ( { children } ) => {
    const [ user, setUser ] = useState( null );
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState( true );
    useEffect( () => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged( async ( user ) => {
            if ( user ) {
                // Utilisez auth.currentUser pour avoir les dernières informations d'authentification de l'utilisateur
                setUser( auth.currentUser );
                setLoading( false );
            } else {
                setUser( null );
                setLoading( false );
            }
        } );
        // Nettoyage : désabonnez-vous de l'événement lorsqu'il n'est plus nécessaire
        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, [] );

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={ { user, loading } }>
            { children }
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Login the user :

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword( email, password )
            .then( async userCredential => {
                navigation.reset( {
                    index: 0,
                    routes: [ { name: "Home" } ],
                } );
            } )
```

firebase.js :

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/compat/storage';
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    databaseURL: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx",
    appId: "xxx"
};

let fireApp;

if ( !firebase.apps.length ) {
    fireApp = firebase.initializeApp( firebaseConfig );
} else {
    fireApp = firebase.app();
}

const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = fireApp.firestore();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export { auth, db, storage };
```

I tried to add `auth.setPersistence( firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL )`

but with this line when I try to login I have an error

```
LOG  error [TypeError: Cannot read property 'setItem' of undefined]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from firebase/compat I solved it when I changed it to firebase classic but this method forced you to modify all your code with db auth storage etc with new firebase method.